# можно ли использовать fetch запрос в github

Tags: javascript, github

https://armensargsyan1993.github.io/boosafolia/

на странице OUR WORKS все основано на fetch запросах(каждая вкладка это отдельная страница) но они работают только если есть server так вот можно ли как то это дело настроит на git чтобы запросы проходили

Comment: вас интересует SPA или Static Site Generation !?

Comment: SPA - да, SSG - нет. в вопросе не вижу упоминания одностраничник, так он интересует?

Comment: ок не принципаильно, интересует чистый JS ? что фетчить будешь

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112268/discussion-between-qwabra-and-armen).

Comment: так гитхаб и предоставляет тебе сервер. Ты можешь точно так же делать к нему запросы, в том числе и с помощью `fetch`

Comment: @Grundy но запросы ведь не проходят ? я зашел в настройки поменял ветку на мастер, сохранил появилось то что с верху, но внутри fetch запросы не работают а если запустить на live server все нормально

Comment: @Armen, ответил в чате

Comment: сори у меня проблема была в путях убрал относительные пути все заработало